What are parameters required for Firebase Rest API?
I want to use Retrofit instead of Firebase SDK for Android to create my app. So what are the parameters I need to pass in headers and how to get those. Till now I have passed token but getting 401 Unauthorized.
class AuthInterceptor(private val authManager: AuthManager) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val token = authManager.getAuthToken()
        val apiKey = authManager.getApiKey()
        val originalRequest =  chain.request()

        val builder = originalRequest.newBuilder()

        if (token != null) {
            builder.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            builder.header("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
        }
        return chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }

}

I am generating the token like this
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val tokenResult = user?.getIdToken(true)?.await()
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("token", tokenResult?.token).apply()
        }

interface APIService {

    @POST("{path}.json")
    fun setData(@Path("path") path: String, @Body hashMap : HashMap<String, Any>): Call<Any>

}

        val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        hashMap.put("infoId", "1")

        val call = apiService.setData("Info", hashMap)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Any> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Any>, response: Response<Any>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = response.body()
                } else {
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Any>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })

class AuthManager @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context : Context) {

    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences("packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun getAuthToken(): String? {
        return sharedPreferences.getString("token", "")
    }

    fun getApiKey():String{
        return "MY API KEY....."
    }
}


If you want to know how the HTTP protocol works, use the documentation.  As for your question "what are the parameters I need to pass in headers and how to get those", it's not clear what specifically you're asking.  We can't see all the relevant code (AuthManager), so we don't know what you might be doing wrong now.
